# mern.io: server.js Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, backend, mern

I'm trying to build a simple app using [mernio](http://mern.io):

```
mern init myApp
cd myApp
npm install
npm start
```

I got the following error:

> /Users/hazemhagrass/workspace/nodejs/vi_mern_server/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:573
>         throw err;
>         ^
>
> SyntaxError:
>   /Users/hazemhagrass/workspace/nodejs/vi_mern_server/server/server.js:
>   Unexpected token (125:10)   123 |       .then(() => {   124 |
>   const initialView = renderToString(
>
> > 125 |           
> >           |           ^   126 |                127 |                  128 |

[image]

Comment: which is your node version?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this post, but have you ensured that the dotfiles from the MERN repository (`.babelrc, .eslintrc, .travis.yml`) are present?